# How can I get notified if someone tries to prevent me from accessing my Gmail or Yahoo! Mail accounts?

Tags: gmail, security, yahoo, passwords

Let's say I have a Gmail or Yahoo! account and another person knows my password. (I had to tell him the password because both of us are using the same account for a common purpose.)

Now, is there are way, like some paid service of Yahoo! or Gmail or whatever, that tells you right away when the password was changed by that other person? For example, it could send e-mails to your alternative e-mail addresses when you change the password.

**But**, what if the other person logs in, deletes my alternate e-mail addresses and changes the password one day, and I am unable to log in to that account? I'll be screwed.

So how do I make sure that I never lose access to my e-mail accounts? Is there any paid service for this purpose? I have been Googling, but it has been in vain.

Comment: What's the common purpose?  Surely there's a better way to collaborate than this.

Comment: @Kyralessa: If I could tell, I would have.

Comment: I think there must be a better option than sharing an e-mail account.  But it's hard to say what it would be without knowing more about what your goals are.

Answer (score 4):

If you give your account's password to another person that means all your accounts information is visible to him and accessible by him. No matter what kind of service you activate by paying money or free. They all will rely on your password and if person knows your password then no one can stop him by cracking your stuff.

***Why don't you change the password before he does?*** This is the only way [As per my knowledge] to prevent him by cracking your account and screw you.

I don't know about Yahoo and GMail specific but some mail accounts provide SMS facility on your mobile but still if person knows your password he can change the mobile number. So the only way to get out of it is to hide your password from others.

***Security question*** is also one thing which he might forget to change and you can get the password changed by him and then change it as per your need.

Comment: I cannot change the password. That's the main problem and I wanna be secure too. There has to be some way. Like I give my credit card details or whatever that won't be visible to this other person..idk there has to be something

Comment: @ILoveMusic: You want privacy but you still want to share your password? You can't make both ends meet.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what the two of you are working on, it's hard to come up with a better option.  But it sounds like you're collaborating on a project and need to be able to send e-mail.

So, what about a FogBugz account?

If there are only two of you, you can get a [free FogBugz account](http://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz/StudentAndStartup.html), which lets you plan your project, send e-mails from within it, receive replies and categorize them, construct a wiki, and several other things.  You can even get an account for more than two people, to use for a class, if you contact them from your college e-mail address.

In this way you could both collaborate, and both send e-mail from the same location, without having to share passwords.